# What does a DesignNavigationService do? (related to MVVM Light toolkit)

Tags: mvvm, windows-8, mvvm-light

In the special Window 8 edition of MSDN Magazine (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine//jj651572.aspx), Laurent describes initialize his SimpleIoc container, and also describes how to implement navigation from the ViewModels using a `NavigationService`, which implements `INavigationService`.

However, in Figure 6, (which he says illustrates how to register the service), his code snippet clearly refers to a *design-time* NavigationService, named `DesignNavigationService`, which I presume is to support "Blendability" (Laurent is very big on supporting Blend, and I appreciate that).

Does anyone know what is different about a design-time navigation service? There's no other mention of it in the article, and a few Bing searches turned up nothing useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in the sample code that was published in conjunction with the article.

In the `DesignNavigationService` class, there's this explanatory comment:

```
// This class doesn't perform navigation, in order
// to avoid issues in the designer at design time.
```

Which, given that the ViewModel classes may be running a little bit at design time, makes sense, now that I think about it.

Comment: Ah the pain of having only 5000 words in an article. Yes you are absolutely right, the DesignNavigationService is here to *prevent* navigation, which could cause issues in the designer :)